# Installing django_auth_ldap / pyldap

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-auth-ldap, pyldap

Installing Python libraries on my Mac is normally relatively problemless, but with my Windows 10 PC I encounter more headaches.
 I'd like to setup an LDAP Authentication Backend in Django, and I've already used ldap3 to confirm a bind, with success.
 I'm now realising that writing a class for my LDAP Backend with just ldap3 is so straightforward, and that installing
 django_auth_ldap could be another route to explore. Doing a simple "pip install " on my Windows PC results in connection
issues, so the following worked with other packages:

```
pip install --trusted-host pipy.python.org <package>
```

This had worked in the past, but it stalls for the django_auth_ldap package, whereby the problem lies when "collecing pyldap".
That's where I get a connectiontimeout error. Is there a way to somehow bypass this error, and why can't I install pyldap?

Comment: If this is the only package you are having issue, you can manually download it from pypi and install it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap

Comment: If you haven't seen it, I highly recommend the `django-python3-ldap` package. https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

Comment: Have you tried just a `pip install pyldap`? Also, I believe you have a typo in your command: `pipy` should be `pypi`.